# Why does my PrintWriter throw exceptions when I try to write on it?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, printwriter

I have a simple ChatClient that sends data to a Server. In order for Chat Client to send data, I make a Socket, make a PrintWriter to the socket.getOutputStream(), then do writer.println(""). For some reason, I get the a big fat exception. I looked at similar exceptions to mine, and a lot of people said to update java. But I have the latest version on my Mac. Is it because I have Leopard, or is it my shoddy programming? Please take a look.

```
private void setUpNetworking() {

        try {
            **sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 65534);**
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

            **writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());**
            System.out.println("made connection... everything here works");

        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("setup fail, but i didn't get this");

        }
    }

    public class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ev){
            try {
                **writer.println(entertext.getText());**
                **writer.flush();**
                System.out.println("PROBLEM IS RIGHT HERE!!!");

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("i get a exception. HELP");

            }
```

Here's my exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SimpleChatClient$SendButtonListener.actionPerformed(SimpleChatClient.java:52)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1882)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2202)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:258)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:246)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5617)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3129)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5382)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2010)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4083)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2068)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3918)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4256)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3936)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3866)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2054)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1801)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3918)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:501)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:462)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:461)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:84)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:95)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:476)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:475)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:473)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:176)
    **at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)**
```

I don't know what this means. Please help.

Comment: either of `writer` or `entertext` is null. Use debugger/SOP to know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your stack trace and notes, it sounds like when you call

```
writer.println(entertext.getText());
```

in the `actionPerformed` method of your `SendButtonListener`, either `writer` `enterText` is null.

Which is null, and how it got that way isn't clear from the code, but you should be able to figure it out with a debugger or logging.

Comment: So I checked my code, and it turns out that writer is null when i call the print. Do i assign it a value, and if so, how? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You've got code in your setupNetworking method that should more or less work for creating the writer, but you need to ensure it's called before you need to send.  You should also make sure you close it properly after using it and that it gets closed if there's an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to debug this - either:

- Put in an individual `println` to print each thing that might be null, just before it has the exception
- or run it in a debugger (Eclipse provides one, for example) and see what the values of the variables are when you get that line

Answer (score 0):

Chekc the line 52 of.SimpleChatClient, something there ir.null